# Need some Excel help getting data from multiple worksheets

Tags: excel

I need some help with Excel please

Let's say I have an Excel workbook that has a worksheet for each person in a company. Each worksheet is the name of the employee and has various information about that employee. I have an index page that has each worksheet name in column A starting on A2. I would like to know how to show the contents of cell D6 from each employees worksheet on the index page.

Thanks

Comment: In whatever cell you want to display the value, type `=` then click on the worksheet of your choice, click on cell `D6` and click `Enter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
=INDIRECT(A2&"!$D$6")
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of your worksheets use a hyphen or other special characters in the name use this instead:
=INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!D6")

This should keep you from getting #REF! errors.